# What is the equivalent of postgresSQL unnest() in snowflake sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unnest

How do i modify the PostgresSQL in snowflake?

```
UNNEST(array[
    'x' || to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', max(date)), 'Mon YYYY' ,
    'y' || to_char(date_trunc('MONTH', max(date)), 'Mon YYYY')
    )])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use "flatten" to break out values from the array, and then "table" to convert the values into a table:

```
-- Use an array for testing:
select array_construct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

-- Flattens into a table with metadata for each row:
select * from table(flatten(input => array_construct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));

--Pulls out just the values from the array:
select value::integer from table(flatten(input => array_construct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
```

The `"::integer"` part casts the values to the data type you want from the array. It's optional but recommended.

You can approximate the syntax of unnest by creating a user defined table function:

```
create or replace function UNNEST(V array)
returns table ("VALUE" variant)
language SQL
aS
$$
    select VALUE from table(flatten(input => V))
$$;
```

You would call it like this:

```
select * from table(unnest(array_construct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
```

This returns a table with a single column named VALUE of type variant. You can make a version that returns strings, integers, etc.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I have used Flatten() and I keep getting an error: SQL compilation error: Unknown function FLATTEN.

Comment: You must use flatten as a table function. That means it will only work inside the parenthesis of a TABLE() function. If you use it outside of the parenthesis of a table() function, you will get that error.